# Rule based extraction from a pandas string using NLP

Tags: python, pandas, text-extraction

I have a sit-in where I am performing a keyword extraction and building a category on top of it which is working fine as I am able to do a `str.contains` for a single keyword.
But what if I want to use a string of keywords and build multiple sub categories on top of it. For example from the column Text I would like to extract the Target Sub Category based on the rules defined below:

```
Text                                         Target Sub Category
invoice received payment sent data csv       Invoice & Payment and Data Request
```

**Rules**

The first part of the Sub Category i.e. `"Invoice & Payment"` is derived from keywords like `"invoice" & "payment"` and the second part of the sub category i.e. `"Data & Information"` is derived from keywords like `"data" and "csv"`.

how can I build something like this. The keywords can come in any order so essentially an intelligent search has to be built to and there are a lot of different keywords on which I would like to build this sub category. Any directional sense that I can build here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using a most brutal loop, and a dict that maps each category name to set of keywords for this category.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['invoice received payment sent data csv', 'data is portrayed by brent spiner']})

category_keywords = {'Invoice & Payment': {'invoice', 'payment'}, 'Data Request': {'data', 'csv'}}

df['Target Sub Category'] = [{cat for word in text.split()
                                  for cat,keywords in category_keywords.items()
                                  if word.lower() in keywords
                             } for text in df['Text']]

print(df)
#                                      Text                Target Sub Category
# 0  invoice received payment sent data csv  {Data Request, Invoice & Payment}
# 1       data is portrayed by brent spiner                     {Data Request}
```